# Setting time to live (TTL) in Azure DocumentDB using MongoDB.Driver 2

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, ttl, mongodb.driver

I'm trying to implement TTL in DocumentDB by using MongoDB.Driver. I created an index like

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync
(
    Builders<T>.IndexKeys.Ascending("_id123"),
    new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) }
);
```

The above code is creating the _id123 index without any errors, but the inserted data is not expiring after 10sec. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: "not working" meaning... what? Is there an error message? Does nothing happen?

Comment: Hi David, the code is not returning any errors, but the inserted document is not getting expired after 10sec.

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience, please have a try to use the `_ts field`. We can get more information from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-time-to-live).
I do a demo for creating TTL index on my side, it works correctly.  The following is the detail steps.

1.Create C# console project and  add  [MongoDB SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/)

2.Add a Person Class

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
public class Person
        {
            public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
```

3.Create MongodB client and we can get the code from Azure portal.

[image]

4.Add document to collection

```
 var db = mongoClient.GetDatabase("dbname");

 var collection = db.GetCollection<Person>("collectionname");

 collection.InsertOne(new Person() {Name = "tom"});
```

5.Check from the Azure portal

[image]

6.Create TTL index on `_ts` field

```
 var indexs = collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Person>.IndexKeys.Ascending("_ts"),
 new CreateIndexOptions { ExpireAfter = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) }).Result;
```

[image]

Package.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.4.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Tom Sun. In my case, the index is being created successfully, but the inserted data is not getting expired after 10sec in the azure DocumentDB. Is the inserted data expiring after 10sec in your test project?

Comment: It works correctly on my side when I set expired after 10sec, after that the document is removed from collection. Please have a try to use such as  100sec to test. In my option 10sec is  a little short for test.

Comment: The TTL feature is controlled by TTL properties at two levels - the collection level and the document level. The values are set in seconds and are treated as a delta from the _ts. Please use the `_ts` filed . More info please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-time-to-live). I have updated my reply.

Comment: This option is obsolete, I've added a new way to do it that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way I've found is:

1. Go to your DB > Configuration > Preview Features > Enable Per-document TTL
   [image]
2. Go to your collection in DB data explorer, Scale & Settings, and set the time you want the objects to live:
   [image]
3. You can specify the TTL for each object when you insert them in DB (this will override the collection TTL established before). You just need to add to your document a field called "ttl" wich is a `double` with the format: `ttl = 3600.0`

And that's it, the documents will delete by themselves after an hour. Good luck!